# SAPUI5 accessing wrong i18n file after enhancement

Tags: javascript, properties, internationalization, sapui5

I'm enhancing the main i18n file in my application like this:

```
var i18n = this.getCallbackAPI().getView().getModel('i18n');
i18n.enhance({bundleUrl:"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/myWorkspace/webapp/app/i18n/i18n.properties"});
```

I have two different .properties files in my bundleUrl:

1. i18n_de.properties
2. i18n_en.properties

For some reason, the application only accesses the english file, even if the language is explicitly set to German in the URL.

I feel like I'm missing some part that enables the dynamic usage of the correct file.

(In the main application, there are two .properties files as well and the application always uses the correct language.)

What am I missing?

Comment: does it access 'i18n_en.properties' or 'i18n.properties' ? your bundle definition seems to refer only to 'i18n.properties' file

Comment: no, it's accessing i18n_en.properties.. For some reason, if I'd define the english file in my bundleURL, it would look for i18n_en_en.properties :D

Comment: Why do you need to enhance the i18n model?

Comment: I built an "add-on" to the main application.Therefore it should be kept seperate from the main application.. @Marc

Comment: @AshKander forgot to mention you..

Comment: I am building an add on right now and use `bundleUrl: "../webapp/i18n/i18n.properties"`. This works for me (apps are deployed in the cloud, not on-premise)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line to your component file : 
oModel is the main model of the application

```
 oModel.aUrlParams[0] = "sap-language=" + 
 sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLanguage();
```

Comment: the language recognition is working fine. in the main application we don't have a problem with accessing the correct file. so there shouldn't have to be changes in the component file. it's only the enhancement that doesn't identify the correct file..

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc from there : https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel/methods/enhance

It seems that you can pass a locale to the bundle at initialization time

If you try

```
var i18n = this.getCallbackAPI().getView().getModel('i18n')
i18n.enhance({
  bundleUrl:"/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/myWorkspace/webapp/app/i18n/i18n.properties",
  bundleLocale:"de"
})
```

Do you get better results ? if so can you check what is returned by

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLocale()
```

Comment: First of all:it's not working that way. 
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().getLocale() returns the correct locale depending on the language I accessed the page (en, de)
second of all: that's not what I've been looking for.. it should adjust dynamically. So when presetting "DE", it would never go to EN right? :/
any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a url in the ressource model you might try as well. Focus on:
**oI18nCustom.getResourceBundle().oUrlInfo.url**.

```
var oI18nBase = this.getModel("i18n");
var oI18nCustom = this.getModel("i18nCustom");
oI18nBase.enhance({bundleUrl: oI18nCustom.getResourceBundle().oUrlInfo.url });
```

In the enhancement app manifest you have to specify the custom i18n model like:

```
"models": {
    ...
        "i18nCustom": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "namespace.path.extensionApp.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    ...
}
```